# MFC. Saving and loading CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl

Tags: c++, stl, mfc

I'm looking for matches and highlights them in color.
After this I display only them.
I need to re-display the entire text with highlighted words.
I have tried to do through `std::stringstream` and `StreamIn` + `StreamOut`, but the color is lost.

```
void RichText::saveInStringstream() 
{ 
    EDITSTREAM es = { 0, 0, editStreamOutCallback }; 
    es.dwCookie = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&m_rtf);   
    m_richEdit.StreamOut(SF_RTF, es); 
} 


DWORD CALLBACK RichText::editStreamOutCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb) 
{ 
    std::stringstream *rtf = reinterpret_cast<std::stringstream *>(dwCookie); 
    rtf->write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(pbBuff), cb); 
    *pcb = cb; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `StreamOut` should work. Have a look at `CRichEditView::Stream`'s body.

Comment: I think I'm doing as well.   
`void RichText::saveInStringstream()
{
    
    EDITSTREAM es = { 0, 0, editStreamOutCallback };
    es.dwCookie = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&m_rtf);

    m_richEdit.StreamOut(SF_RTF, es);    
}`  

`DWORD CALLBACK RichText::editStreamOutCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{        
    std::stringstream *rtf = reinterpret_cast<std::stringstream *>(dwCookie);   
    
    rtf->write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(pbBuff), cb);       
    
    *pcb = cb;    

    return 0;
}`  


But the source text remains in the stream.

Comment: It's impossible to read this much code in comments. Please click the edit button and include this information in your question.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani
 
Okay. I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still found a solution but using `CMemFile`.

```
void RichStream::Save(CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl &richEdit)
{    
    file.SeekToBegin();

    EDITSTREAM es = { 0, 0, editStreamOutCallback };
    es.dwCookie = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&file);

    richEdit.StreamOut(SF_RTF, es);      
}

void RichStream::Load(CMFCRibbonRichEditCtrl &richEdit)
{   
    file.SeekToBegin();

    EDITSTREAM es = { 0, 0, editStreamInCallback };
    es.dwCookie = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&file);    

    richEdit.StreamIn(SF_RTF, es);
}

DWORD CALLBACK RichStream::editStreamOutCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    CMemFile* pFile = (CMemFile*)dwCookie;

    pFile->Write(pbBuff, cb);

    *pcb = cb;

    return 0;   
}

DWORD CALLBACK RichStream::editStreamInCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    CMemFile* pFile = (CMemFile*)dwCookie;

    *pcb = pFile->Read(pbBuff, cb);

    return 0;
}
```